# How to get publisher name in apalike

Tags: apa-style

I want to modify the bst file of apalike to print the volume,Issue,publisher_name and published_year of articles on bibliography of my thesis.How can I do it?

Comment: Could you consider using `biblatex-apa`?

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why do you wish to report *publisher_name* of a journal? Would any of your readers care in the least bit? I, for one, highly doubt it. For sure, the `apalike` bibliography style does print out the year a piece was published if the `year` field is non-empty.